# Limiting email extensions submitted in an HTML text form

Tags: php, forms

How can I limit the email address extension that can be submitted in an HTML `form` using PHP? For example, I want to require that all users enter an `@gmail.com` email address.

---

EDIT: I have tried using `if` statements and `substr()` to return the last ten characters in the submitted email address (which, if it contains the correct email address extension, should be `@gmail.com`). However, this is probably not the most efficient/secure method. Does anyone know any other, more secure approaches to solving this task.

Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = trim(strtolower($_POST['email']));

    if(substr($email, -10) != '@gmail.com') {
        //show error message here
    } else {
        //continue script
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new html 5 elements should let you do this as they will accept a 'pattern' attribute that you can plug a regex into to restrict the end of the string to @gmail.com. You can do the same thing with javacsript/jquery and validate the form against a script on submission. \@gmail.com$ should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yea man, what whiterainbow said is good, but its client side validation, which can easily be bypassed. You should do that, but also check for it in the form validation php script. Should be something like this:

```
/*Say the user entered email_add@gmail.com*/
$website = explode("@", $_POST['email']);
/*$website is now => array(0 => "email_add", 1 => "gmail.com")*/
$website = end($website);      // Grab the last element of the array

if($website != "gmail.com")
{// Show some error here}

/*SUBSTITUTE METHOD: A Shorter method that elias suggested in a comment below*/
if (!stristr($_POST['email'],'@gmail.com'))
{// Show some error here}
```

P.S - There is a shorter way to get the last element of an array and explode, cant remember it off my head tho... Google it

Comment: won't work: `$website[count[$website]];` has syntax error. should be `$website[count($website)]`, but that still won't work: count returns 2... so should be `$website[count($website)-1]`, or just `$website[1]`.
better still: `$website = end($website);` or `array_pop($website)`. A simpler solution would be `if (stristr($_POST['email'],'@gmail.com'))`

Comment: Thanks Elias, Gonna edit the answer, just wanted to give the guy the idea of what to do.